# How get id class using VBA on EXCEL?

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to coding some VBA..This VBA will need get some value from cell that is an URL.
The VBA must be open this URL and get some class id on this page and returns the values.

Is it Simple?

Example:

1- A1 = www.google.com

2- the VBA will open A1 values

3- the VBA will get some class ID on this page.

4- the VBA will returns on A2 this values.

**Code from OP's answer post**

```
Sub FetchData()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://www.google.com", Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1"))
        .Name = "67083361_zpid"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code and let us know what you are unable to figure out.

Comment: HTML can contain multiple elements attributed with a certain *class* but is only supposed to have one element per unique *id*. Your statement *"...get some class id on this page ..."* seems to mash-up the two attributes making it unclear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should get you enough:

```
Public Function GetHttpResponse(URL As String) As String
    Dim Request As Object, Result As String
    Set Request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    Request.Open "GET", URL
    Request.Send
    Result = Request.ResponseText
    Set Request = Nothing
    GetHttpResponse = Result
End Function

Public Function GetNodeByPath(ResponseText As String, Path As String) As String
    Dim Result As String, DOM As Object
    Set DOM = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    DOM.async = False
    DOM.validateOnParse = False
    DOM.LoadXML ResponseText
    DOM.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    Dim NodeList As Object
    Set NodeList = DOM.SelectNodes(Path)
    Dim Node As Object
    Result = ""
    For Each Node In NodeList
        Result = Node.Text
        Exit For
    Next
    Set DOM = Nothing
    Set NodeList = Nothing
    Set Node = Nothing
    GetNodeByPath = Result
End Function
```

Then you just:

```
=GetNodeByPath(GetHttpResponse("http://website.com/"),"/html/body/div[2]")
```

Which means: retrieve page from `website.com` and get the contents of the second `div` tag inside `body` tag inside `html` tag.

Comment: When you say.."Then you just".. What means...I am not expert on VBA.

Comment: Then you just paste this formula into a cell! :D